# Appium/ WinAppDriver: Unable to Automate .jnlp applications - The specified Executable is not a valid application for this OS Platform

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, jnlp, winappdriver

I am trying to automate .jnlp applications located on remote machine. Developers have built .bat files to launch .jnlp Apps. JNLP apps uses Java to launch/open.

I am using Appium.Webdriver to launch/ Automate these apps. Below is my code

**Tools**: C#, Visual Studio, Appium.Webdriver, WinAppDriver, .Net 5.0, Selenium

```
    public const string DriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/";
    public WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> DesktopSession;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
      //Start WinappDriver
      Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinappDriver.exe");
      Thread.Sleep(3000);

      // Start jnlp application
      Process.Start(@"\\<folderPath>\launch-App.bat");
      Thread.Sleep(20000);

      AppiumOptions Options = new AppiumOptions();
      Options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", @"\\<RemoteFolderPath>\JnlpApp.jnlp");           
      Options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
      Options.AddAdditionalCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch", "20");
      Options.AddAdditionalCapability("appWorkingDir", @"\\<AppFolderPath>");
    
      try
      {
        DesktopSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(DriverUrl), Options);
        Assert.IsNotNull(DesktopSession);
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
      }
    }
```

**Exception**: The specified Executable is not a valid application for this OS Platform

**Note**: Application is launched successfully. But DesktopSession is set null.